# Lifetime error only when function written as a closure

Tags: rust

There seems to be a difference in lifetime inference between normal functions and functions defined as closures. Consider the following minimal example:

```rust
fn foo(f: &String) -> &str {
    f
}

fn bar() {
    |f: &String| -> &str { f };
}
```

The compiler (Rustc 1.69.0 with `--edition=2021`) accepts `foo`, but rejects the closure in `bar` (which is the same function as foo) with the error

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
 --> clos.rs:8:33
  |
8 |     move |f: &String| -> &str { f };
  |              -           -      ^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
  |              |           |
  |              |           let's call the lifetime of this reference `'2`
  |              let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
```

In the case of `foo`, my understanding is that the compiler desugars it to

```
fn foo<'a>(f: &'a String) -> &'a str { ... }
```

Why doesn't it do the same for the closure? And is there some way I can manually specify the lifetimes myself (in particular, where would I place the `<'a>` to declare the lifetime)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because for functions, there is never any captured state, therefore the lifetimes of the input and output are almost always connected. For closures, the lifetimes could be from the environment.

You can make a function that generates the closure, which lets you use `impl Fn` syntax, which seems to infer lifetimes correctly, at least in this case. If you capture any state, you will need to pass that as an argument to the generator function.

```rs
fn generate() -> impl Fn(&String) -> &str {
    |f: &String| -> &str { f }
}
```

If it doesn't work for a certain case, you can use `for` syntax to specify the lifetimes explicitly.

```rs
fn generate_for() -> impl for<'a> Fn(&'a String) -> &'a str {
    |f: &String| -> &str { f }
}
```

There's a nightly feature for this: `closure_lifetime_binder`. When stabilized, it will allow you to add `for` annotations to closure expressions instead of only to traits.

```rs
#![feature(closure_lifetime_binder)]

fn bar_nightly() {
    for<'a> |f: &'a String| -> &'a str { f };
}
```

Comment: That makes sense - notably the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html) on lifetime elision makes no reference to type annotations in closure expressions. I'm curious if there's a source anywhere confirming that the possibility of captured lifetimes is the reason why.

Comment: Thanks. The explanation seems a bit odd, since Rust already uses the body of a closure to infer the return type, and hence could plausibly also be expected to infer the lifetime of the return. But your solution does seem to work for this minimal example. I'll check if it works for my real use case (which involves capture) and so I'll accept it.

Comment: I ran into some more difficulties with my actual use case because I don't know the concrete return type of the closure (it calls an async fn, so the type is `impl Future<...>`) and you can't use `impl Trait` as a Fn trait return type. But that's probably a whole new question.